# How do I get the ID of the previous step execution in the next step of a spring batch job?

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing

How do I get the ID of the previous step execution in the next step of a spring batch job?

I am currently trying to perform several steps on a single set of data and persisting them in different rows in a database.

Each step (except the first one) will be reading the previous steps results and doing further processing on it and then saving the updated results in a new row.

I have a custom reader which reads from the database but I need to pass the ID of the previous step execution to the current step so that it can query the repository accordingly.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow following steps below :

1.From current Step, pass data to `StepExecutionContext`.

2.From Current `StepExecutionContext`, pass data to `JobExecutionContext`(through a `listener`)

3.`JobExecutionContext` is shared across all Steps and in this way you can now get data of   previous `Steps`.

Alternative approach will be to store this temp **Step** data in a table in DB with columns as `JobExecutionId,StepExecutionId,StepData`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it matter if we store the information in the JobExecutionContext directly? I did this using @AfterStep and then saved it directly to the JobExecutionContext and it worked correctly

Comment: Yes even that would work.Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use a `StepExecutionListener` that will be called before and after the step is executed.
The method `afterStep` has the `StepExecution` object. You can use this `StepExecution` to set all the parameters you need on the next step.

Ex.:

```
currentStep.registerStepExecutionListener(new StepExecutionListener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {}

        @Override
        public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            nextStep.setParameter(stepExecution.getExecutionContext().getString(param)
            return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
        }
    });
```